# SAS coding for generating permutation of multiple field values

Tags: sas

Would anyone kindly be able to help me with following SAS related coding problem?

I have 3 input datasets (A, B, C) with different levels of unique inputs, i.e. 3 cities / 3 professions and 2 age groups as below:

INPUT DATA - A

```
CITY
----------
LONDON
BIRMINGHAM
MANCHESTER
```

INPUT DATA - B

```
PROFSSIONS
----------
TEACHER
STUDENTS
ADMIN
```

INPUT DATA - C

```
AGE
-------
18 - 40
40 - 60
```

I’d like to have an output table [Called: O] as below, with 18 [3x3x2] rows:

FINAL OUTPUT: TABLE - O

```
CITY         PROFSSIONS   AGE
---------------------------------
LONDON       TEACHER      18 - 40
LONDON       TEACHER      40 - 60
LONDON       STUDENTS     19 - 40
LONDON       STUDENTS     41 - 60
LONDON       ADMIN        20 - 40
LONDON       ADMIN        42 - 60
BIRMINGHAM   TEACHER      18 - 40
BIRMINGHAM   TEACHER      40 - 60
BIRMINGHAM   STUDENTS     19 - 40
BIRMINGHAM   STUDENTS     41 - 60
BIRMINGHAM   ADMIN        20 - 40
BIRMINGHAM   ADMIN        42 - 60
MANCHESTER   TEACHER      18 - 40
MANCHESTER   TEACHER      40 - 60
MANCHESTER   STUDENTS     19 - 40
MANCHESTER   STUDENTS     41 - 60
MANCHESTER   ADMIN        20 - 40
MANCHESTER   ADMIN        42 - 60
```

Many thanks.

Nad

Comment: The join type here is called a cross join, which is implicitly implied in SRSwift code.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) of three datasets. There are several ways to achieve this but the simplest is probably:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select *
    from a, b, c;
quit;
```